# How to create an identical button to the one in 'Settings' page?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to create buttons on my UWP/XAML app similar to the buttons on the Windows 'Settings' page using the WinUI 3 library. The gallery didn't show this kind of button with an icon and a title/description. I'm wondering how it can be accomplished since I am developing an app that mostly serves as a portal to go to websites and navigate easily through web/PC apps. Any help would be appreciated.

I want the buttons to simply redirect the user to a NavigationView page (Page5.xaml)

I have a NavigationView on MainPage.xaml and these buttons are going on Page4, so I'm not sure how I can program the buttons to go to Page5.xaml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uff8.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create a usercontrol and use some of my code:

MyUserControl.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited" PointerPressed="FontIcon_PointerPressed" Margin="20,5,20,5" Height="70" CornerRadius="5" Padding="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderPadding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{ThemeResource ExpanderHeaderBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ExpanderHeaderBorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ExpanderHeaderBorderBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE8D2;" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Font"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <FontIcon  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE76C;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
public MyUserControl1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var color = (MainGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
    color.A = 20;
    MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
}

private void FontIcon_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement).Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
    {
        //Do whatever you want
        Debug.WriteLine("Pressed");
    }
}

//Change the color on hover:
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var color = (MainGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
    color.A = 50;
    MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var color = (MainGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
    color.A = 20;
    MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```